# Does anyone knows what's the name of the tool this diagram is written in?

Tags: diagram

I've seen such diagrams on many websites, including [HgInit](http://hginit.com/02.html) and I like the looks of them.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sketching style looks similar to Balsamiq Mockups software